# SQL Injection attempt, what does this query attempt to do?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-injection, union

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Site has been hacked via SQL Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4600954/site-has-been-hacked-via-sql-injection)

Looks like one of my websites had a hacker attempt on it, my reports showed the following querystring data attempted:

```
QUERY_STRING = ID=-999.9%20UNION%20ALL%20SELECT%200x31303235343830303536,0x31303235343830303536,0x31303235343830303536,0x31303235343830303536,0x31303235343830303536,0x31303235343830303536,0x31303235343830303536,0x31303235343830303536,0x31303235343830303536,0x31303235343830303536,0x31303235343830303536,0x31303235343830303536,0x31303235343830303536,0x31303235343830303536,0x31303235343830303536,0x31303235343830303536,0x31303235343830303536,0x31303235343830303536,0x31303235343830303536,0x31303235343830303536-
```

It failed because any integer parameter I always cast to an integer so you get mismatch errors if anything like this is tried (classic ASP).  But I'm confused what the query above is attempting?  It doesn't look like anything I've seen before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

take a look at: 
[Site has been hacked via SQL Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4600954/site-has-been-hacked-via-sql-injection)

at a first look a guess it was some automatic tool doing some blind sql injection.

Comment: You'd normally vote as "close as duplicate" or flag it, but I see you don't have enough reputation

Comment: You have enough to "flag" now :-)

Comment: But do you really think that I should flag it?! I don't want to do it. Flag is just a bad word :p

Comment: @Rui Lima: I'm sure @gbn was talking about 'flagging' in a broader sense. He meant voting for closing the question, undoubtedly. (Just wanted to clarify it.)