# SQL Injection Trap - what does this mean

Tags: mysql, sql-injection

In the past, when I see someone try to mess with input vars - I just block their IP...  but it seems they just use a different IP and try again.  So, I have setup traps to alert me when there is an attempt and try to figure out what they are trying to get, so I can fix any possible vulnerabilities.

I had an attempt, they changed a var to this:

-999.9 /*!30000 UNION ALL SELECT 0x31303235343830303536,0x31303235343830303536,0x31303235343830303536,0x31303235343830303536,0x31303235343830303536,0x31303235343830303536,0x31303235343830303536,0x31303235343830303536,0x31303235343830303536,0x31303235343830303536,0x31303235343830303536,0x31303235343830303536,0x31303235343830303536,0x31303235343830303536,0x31303235343830303536,0x31303235343830303536,0x31303235343830303536,0x31303235343830303536,0x31303235343830303536,0x31303235343830303536,0x31303235343830303536,0x31303235343830303536,0x31303235343830303536,0x31303235343830303536,0x31303235343830303536,0x31303235343830303536,0x31303235343830303536,0x31303235343830303536,0x31303235343830303536,0x31303235343830303536*/--

I was hoping someone could help explain what this means?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Site has been hacked via SQL Injection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4600954/site-has-been-hacked-via-sql-injection)

Comment: A quick search for `0x31303235343830303536` yields several results in this very boutique.  Marked as duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The attacker is trying to inject a UNION SELECT that is wrapped in a [MySQL’s variant of C style comments](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comments.html), which allow a conditional exclusion of the contents.

In this case the comment would not be considered a comment if the MySQL version is greater or equal to 3.0.0. In that case a UNION SELECT with [strings in hexadecimal notation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/hexadecimal-literals.html) (i. e., `0x31303235343830303536`) equivalent to `'1025480056'` gets appended to the existing statement. Any remaining code in the same line is ignored by injecting the line-end comment `--` .